# Error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy

I am pretty new to python/numpy and is not completely aware of it.

I have been trying to implement an algorithm and getting stuck at a certain point where when trying to take the dot product of an array with its transpose. The error that I am getting is this

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Below is my code for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset=pd.read_csv('SCLC_study_output_filtered_2.csv',header=0,delimiter=",")

#forming the first class
class_1 = dataset.iloc[0:20,1:20].values

#forming the second class
class_2 = dataset.iloc[20:41,1:20].values

mean_c1 = np.mean(class_1, axis=0)

#Taking mean of class 2 
mean_c2 = np.mean(class_2, axis=0)

mean_classes =[mean_c1,mean_c2]

#Calculating S-within for class-1
scatter_within_c1 = np.zeros((19,19))
for i in range(0,20):
    for col in class_1:
        col, m = col.reshape(19,1), mean_c1.reshape(19,1)
        sub = np.subtract(col,m)
        scatter_within_c1 += np.prod(sub,np.transpose(sub))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs for `np.prod()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

> ```
> numpy.prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=<class numpy._globals._NoValue>)
> ```
>
> Return the product of array elements over a given axis.

The `np.prod()` function is not meant for two different arrays. For the dot product, you can use the [`np.dot()` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) or, equivalently,
 the [`ndarray.dot()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html):

```
>>> A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> np.dot(A, A)
55
>>> A.dot(A)
55
```

Comment: I accepted it as the answer, but since my reputation on Stack Overflow is not 15, hence it's not showing I guess.

Comment: @Ishan I believe you need 15 reputation to *upvote* an answer, but not to accept it. To accept an answer, you just click on the check mark underneath the vote count. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more (including a pic).